# How can I tell Gitlab to mirror my Github repositories over the API?

Tags: api, github, gitlab, mirroring

I have seen that the Gitlab WebUI allows to set-up mirroring for repositories from e.g. Github (under MyCoolRepository --> Settings --> Repository --> Mirroring repositories).

I have seen that this is possible over the API, too: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#start-the-pull-mirroring-process-for-a-project

Does anyone know how this works and which parameters the API needs for `id`?

I wanted to automate this process in a script because I do not want to set-up the automatic mirroring for each repository in Gitlab by hand...

Comment: Solution is in this question by the way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52576871/5536006

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the docs specify, you just need to use the project ID, which you can see on:

> MyCoolRepository --> Settings --> General

Or use the [URL-encoded-path](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#namespaced-path-encoding)

As far as the docs say, there is no way to set up this miroring configuration.

Comment: That's how far I understood it as well. But how does Gitlab know where it has to mirror to/ from? Don't I have to set the origin somehow?

Comment: Hi @djuarez, I have added another question here on how to change the mirroring settings. Maybe, you know this, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52554811/how-can-i-change-the-mirroring-settings-in-gitlab-over-the-api